# How to join multiple tables (more than 2) in SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-view

I am attempting to join 4 tables, some of the tables have related columns (i.e. `employeeID` and `customerID`) but not all the tables are related.

I am tasked with creating a view which returns SalesRep First Name and Last Name, Rate of Comission, Comission Earned, and grouped by customer and sorted by Orders.

This is the code I currently have, but I get an error

> Incorrect Syntax near Product Order

Code:

```
CREATE VIEW salesRep5_vw
AS
    SELECT 
        e.firstName AS 'First Name', 
        e.lastName AS 'Last Name',
        sr.comissionRate AS 'Rate Of Comission',
        sr.comissionEarned AS 'Earned Comission',
        c.lastName AS 'Customer Last Name',
        po.orderID AS 'Customer's Related Order ID'
    FROM 
        Employee AS e
    JOIN
        SalesRep AS sr ON e.employeeID = sr.employeeID
    JOIN
        Customer AS c 
    JOIN
        ProductOrder AS po ON c.customerID = po.customerID
```

Any ideas on why this throws an error? I am brand new to this.

Comment: Your join Customer as c has no "ON" clause: should be something like Customer as c ON sr.employeeID = c.EmployeeID (or whatever column they share in common, I'm just guessing here).

Comment: Also, the column alias on your last column in the `SELECT` is bad - if you have a single quote in the name, you need to double-up the contained single quotes

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because it is missing a join condition for the `customer` table:

```
select ...
from Employee as e 
join SalesRep as sr on e.employeeID = sr.employeeID 
join Customer as c     --> here
join ProductOrder as po on c.customerID = po.customerID
```

You said:

> some of the tables have related columns [...] but not all the tables are related.

I doubt that. You would have to look closer at your database structure to find how the customer table relates to the others.

Presumably, you want to bring an order is related to a sales rep, and to a customer, so you *might* be looking for something like:

```
select ...
from Employee as e 
join SalesRep as sr on e.employeeID = sr.employeeID 
join ProductOrder as po on po.salesrepID = sr.salesrepID
join Customer as c on c.customerID = po.customerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket `[]` to represent *lateral* string :

```
select e.firstName as [First Name],
       e.lastName as [Last Name],
       sr.comissionRate as [Rate Of Comission],
       sr.comissionEarned as [Earned Comission],
       c.lastName as [Customer Last Name],
       po.orderID as [Customer's Related Order ID]
from Employee as e join 
     SalesRep as sr
     ON e.employeeID = sr.employeeID join 
     Customer as c          
     ON . . .  join
     ProductOrder as po
     on c.customerID = po.customerID
```

Also, `JOIN` will require `ON` clause. Some of the `JOIN`s doesn't have a `ON` clause.